# Is SmcFanControl safe to use on 2015 MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, applications, cooling

My 2015 MacBook hasn't got any hotter then it normally does since I brought it. The only issue is not it is the hot weather my 2015 MBP is now making me feel hot (due to feeling the heat on my lap).

To fix this issue I would like to use an application such as [SmcFanControl](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23049/smcfancontrol). Is this updated for the retina 2015 MBP and will I be able to set my fans back to auto when I don't need the application any more?

Thanks

Comment: @Buscar웃SD What if I do the exact same stuff as a usually do (The stuff I do never sets the fans off)

Comment: That should be fine, but I just avoid 3d party apps specialty the one that interfere with the hardware. From design point, the fans are not meant to run full blast all the time.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD The fans won't be at full blast. It will be enough to keep it cool. No more. Don't want to hear the noisy fans!

Answer (score 3):

I think it is safe to use, since the latest update has a reset function:

> New: Reset-Feature to reset fans back to factory defaults, delete settings and favorites

I've also red somewhere they fixed SmcFanControl on newer macs.

Comment: This doesn't fit quite to the question/answer, but I once used this program too cool my keyboard on a old macbook (2007 if i'm right) on hot days. It worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a MacBook and not a MacBook Pro you don't have to use SmcFanControl, but if you have a Pro it is safe to use smcFanControl. I'm using this utility to cool down my MacBook Pro 2010 when the days are hot, and everything works just fine. You can choose a bottom level for coolers' rmp and if the system needs more rmp the smcFanControl won't stop the coolers from increasing the rpm.

Hope I was helpful.

Comment: Why don't you have to use SmcFanControl on a normal macbook? I don't have a normal macbook anymore, but it worked on it. It even cooled my keyboard on these hot days.

Comment: I mean a MacBook 2015, which comes with no fans at all, because it has an Intel Core-M CPU with a 15W (I might be wrong), and the max temp that this cpu can hit is around 45 celsius degrees.

Comment: I thought you meant the macbook from 2007. Learned something new today!

Comment: Just found out that the app doesn't work. My fans haven't changed at all.

Answer (score 1):

I often need to fire up the fans on various Mac laptops for testing, and decided to find something more up to date quite recently.

I now use [iStat Menus](http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/), which in addition to temperature readouts, which are rather useful in this context, it shows the current speed of the fan(s) and allows you to select from three presets to ramp them up. You can also adjust them using a slider, if you're into that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Once you change the fan settings in SMC, you then need to close the software and re-open it before the changes take effect.  Not sure why it does this, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out SmcFanControl doesn't work. I tried changing settings and my fans haven't came on at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are several other settings that can be modified in order to stop some of the race conditions that can afflict Macs. For example, see this article, though it deals with a MacBook Air, the same principles apply:

- [OSX Approach to Cooling](https://mcneill.io/idiotic-osx-approach-to-cooling/)

And yes, to your orginal question, smcFanControl works well and should not harm your computer, and indeed as it allows a lower fan speed setting, it could conceivably have less wear and tear on the hardware.

- [smcFanControl on Github](https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl)

Comment: That "OSX Approach to Cooling" is very dangerous. The author misunderstands what `kernel_task` is, and advises to disable termperature-based CPU throttling. That could burn out your computer.

Here's Apple's explanation: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207359

Comment: @misterbee you obviously don't understand the article, the other resources linked, nor have you experienced the problem or tried the solution (smcFanControl). "Very dangerous" without any evidence or explanation is what fear and ignorance breed. Apple doesn't do everything right all the time, and this is one situation where it doesn't work. That said, this is information from 2017, so things may have changed. I certainly don't use apple products anymore.

Comment: My comment was not about smcFanControl at all. It was about the blog post's inaccurate description of `kernel_task`

Comment: Google "Rhys oxenham kernel_task" for more info. Claiming someone is being inaccurate without explaining "how" is not very helpful and is a bit trollish.